# Date variable assignment from a query

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am having some trouble with assigning a variable of type date in a MySQL trigger. When I try to compare my variable to the current date it doesn't work properly.

```
    CREATE TRIGGER actualizar_numero_sesiones AFTER INSERT ON registroingresos
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN 
    DECLARE d date;
    DECLARE vigente INT(11);
    DECLARE vencido INT(11);
    DECLARE state varchar(10);
    select p.fecha_fin into d from compra_paquete cp, paquetes p where cp.ci = new.ci AND         p.idpaquete = cp.idpaquete;
    SET vencido = d > CURDATE();
    SET vigente = d < CURDATE();
    IF (vencido = 1) THEN
      SET state = 'Vencido';
    IF ELSE(vigente = 1) THEN 
       SET state = 'Vigente';
    END IF;
END;
```

The query where I assign the variable d is a date value from the "paquetes" table the problem is that the assignment of d variable it's not working properly because I know the dates that are compared fecha_fin ='2012-04-06' and CURDATE() it's after fecha_fin the state value should be "vencido" but it is "vigente"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does the variable `status`?

You may be able to simplify it a bit with the following statement:

```sql
...
SET `state` := (
    SELECT IF(`p`.`fecha_fin` > CURDATE(), 'Vencido', 'Vigente')
    FROM `compra_paquete` `cp`, `paquetes` `p`
    WHERE `cp`.`ci` = NEW.`ci` AND `p`.`idpaquete` = `cp`.`idpaquete`
);
...
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6ec67/4)</kbd>